# APEX: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, error

**I'm getting the following error:**

> Attempt to de-reference a null object page test11 の式「{!selectGoods}」にエラーがあります: Class.testController.selectGoods: line 49, column 1

**apex class:**

```
public class testController {

    public List<T002__c> tDetailList {
        get;set;
    }
   //売上データ
    public T001__c t {get;
       set;}

  //商品リスト
    public List<M002__c>  mList {
         get;set;
    }  
    public testController() {
       //初期化
        t= new  T001__c();

       mList = new List<M002__c>();
       tDetailList = new List<T002__c>();


    }
      //商品を取得
      public static List<SelectOption> getSyouhinnOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> SyouhinnOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        SyouhinnOptions = syouhinnDAO.getSelectOptionList();
        return    SyouhinnOptions;

    }   


       //受注商品情報を取得
    public PageReference   selectGoods() {




       Integer currentRow = Integer.valueof(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('theRow'));

        Integer currentRowNow = currentRow-1;
         system.debug('currentRow' + currentRow);
          String goodsCode =  tDetailList[currentRowNow].Name;
        system.debug('goodsCode' + goodsCode);

                M002__c goods = syouhinnDAO.getSelectShouhinnByGoodsCode(goodsCode);  
                      system.debug('shuchu1' + goods.M00202__c );
                      system.debug('shuchu1' + goods.M00203__c );
               system.debug('currentRowNow' + currentRowNow);
               tDetailList[currentRowNow].M002__r.M00202__c = goods.M00202__c;   // <------ line 49
               tDetailList[currentRowNow].M002__r.M00203__c = goods.M00203__c;
               tDetailList[currentRowNow].M002__r.M00204__c = goods.M00204__c;
               tDetailList[currentRowNow].M002__r.M00205__c = goods.M00205__c;
         // update   tDetailList[currentRowNow];
        return null;
    }

 //リストの追加    
    public PageReference add() {
        T002__c  t= new  T002__c();
        Integer theRows = tDetailList.size();
        Integer i = 0;
       for(i=0; i<theRows; i++){
           system.debug(i);
         String goodsCode = tDetailList[i].Name;
         system.debug(goodsCode);
         if (goodsCode != null){
             M002__c goods = syouhinnDAO.getSelectShouhinnByGoodsCode(goodsCode);  

             tDetailList[i].M002__r.M00202__c = goods.M00202__c;
             tDetailList[i].M002__r.M00203__c = goods.M00203__c;
             tDetailList[i].M002__r.M00204__c = goods.M00204__c;
             tDetailList[i].M002__r.M00205__c = goods.M00205__c;
           }
        }
      tDetailList.add(t);
      return null;
   }

}
```

**visualforce page:**

```
<apex:page controller="testController" docType="html-5.0">
<html>
     <head>
           <div style="font-size: 32px;">受注入力</div>
     </head>
</html>
<apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >

       <apex:commandButton value="追加"  rerender="theTable" action="{!add}" />
           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tDetailList}" var="goods" id="theTable">
               <apex:variable var="rowIndex" value="0"/>
               <apex:column id="rowindex">
                  <apex:facet name="header">項番</apex:facet>
                  {!rowIndex}
                 <apex:variable var="rowIndex" value="{!VALUE(rowIndex) + 1}" />
               </apex:column>

                <apex:column id="name">
                    <apex:facet name="header">商品名</apex:facet>
                     <apex:selectList id="selectedGoods" value="{!goods.Name}" size="1" >
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!selectGoods}" rerender="theTable" >
                            <apex:param name="theRow" value="{!VALUE(rowIndex)-1 }"/>
                        </apex:actionSupport>
                        <apex:selectOption />
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!SyouhinnOptions}"  />
                    </apex:selectList>
                 </apex:column>

                       <apex:column id="code">
                    <apex:facet name="header">商品コード</apex:facet>
                     {!goods.M002__r.Name}
                 </apex:column>

                 <apex:column id="price" >
                    <apex:facet name="header">単価</apex:facet>
                    {!goods.M002__r.M00203__c}
                 </apex:column>

                 <apex:column id="unit">
                    <apex:facet name="header">単位</apex:facet>
                     {!goods.M002__r.M00204__c}
                 </apex:column>

                 <apex:column id="quantity">
                    <apex:facet name="header">売上数量</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!goods.M002__r.M00207__c}" />
                 </apex:column>
　　　　　　　　  

                 </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please provide add the code on line 49 as separate part of your question, as no linenumbers are present on stackexchange. Thank you!

Comment: It seems like syouhinnDAO.getSelectShouhinnByGoodsCode(goodsCode) method is returning null and method definition is not added to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Either `tDetailList[i].M002__r` is null, or `goods` is null. Consider changing your code slightly:

```
     if (goodsCode != null){
       M002__c goods = syouhinnDAO.getSelectShouhinnByGoodsCode(goodsCode);  
       if(goods != null) {
         tDetailList[i].M002__r = goods.clone();
       }
     }
```

Or, if you literally just need those four fields:

```
     if (goodsCode != null){
       M002__c goods = syouhinnDAO.getSelectShouhinnByGoodsCode(goodsCode);  
       if(goods != null) {
         tDetailList[i].M002__r = new M002__c();
         tDetailList[i].M002__r.M00202__c = goods.M00202__c;
         tDetailList[i].M002__r.M00203__c = goods.M00203__c;
         tDetailList[i].M002__r.M00204__c = goods.M00204__c;
         tDetailList[i].M002__r.M00205__c = goods.M00205__c;
       }
     }
```